# Where are wrappers for .NET and ArcGIS 10x?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, installation, .net

With prior versions (to ArcGIS 10x) of ArcGIS, the .NET wrappers used to be placed in a dotnet directory.

Where are they located with 10x?

With prior versions, I used the absence or presence of this directory to tell whether or not the .net framework was installed in the proper order with installation of ArcGIS.

How can I tell if the .net framework was installed in the correct order with respect to ArcGIS?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think arcgis won't install unless the .NET framework 3.5 sp1 is installed, see requirements [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisdesktop/10.0/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements#ArcGISDesktop-SoftwareRequirements).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to install the SDK seperately, so you will see a 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0' folder that has the 'DotNet' folder with the assemblies. 
The .Net extension stuff is auto-installed now since ArcGIS forces a .Net version for install. So you don't need to specify it; you just need to push to install the SDK.

Comment: Interesting. So if I develop an application for another individual, does the SDK need to be installed for the other person to use it?

Comment: No, because the assemblies are already in there GAC when ArcGIS is installed, these are just the version you use to write your code with. If you have a version dependency you can surely package them with your runtime, but realistically you should not need to.

Comment: There is NO difference between the assemblies installed in GAC and those shipped with the SDK. The latter are additionally installed just for convenience.

Comment: @Petr; with the exception of some of the XML supporting infomration for Intellisense and being Debug build I believe, versus release.

Comment: In case of PIAs, debug/release is irrelevant since they do not contain any executable code but merely COM import declarations (they are generated via tlbimp.exe).

Comment: You also have to install Visual Studio 2008 SP1+, otherwise it won't work with ArcObjects installation for ArcGIS 10.

Comment: @Dexter, yes we use VS2010 without issue.